# QTreeView and delegates(

Tags: qt, delegates

```
class TimeLineDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
TimeLineDelegate(QObject *o):QItemDelegate(o){}
void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
    const QModelIndex &index);
QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index);
};
```

I created this delegate for custom drawing QTreeWidget or QTreeView
but it not work,`TimeLineDelegate::paint` is not called
I try with QTreeWidget and QTreeView, for example

```
QTreeView *myView = new QTreeView();
TimeLineDelegate *delegat = new TimeLineDelegate(myView);
myView->setItemDelegate(new TimeLineDelegate(this));

QStandardItemModel *myModel = new QStandardItemModel();
QStandardItem *parentItem = myModel->invisibleRootItem();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(
        QString("item %0").arg(i));
    parentItem->appendRow(item);
    if (i == 0)
        parentItem = item;
    else {
        item->setData(34);
    }}
    myView->setModel(myModel);

    myView->show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `const` specifier for `paint` method. See [full signature](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint)

Comment: derzai, bud' vnimatelnee :)